# can we store LocalMediaStream locally?

Tags: html, local-storage, getusermedia

in WebRTC , getUserMedia() gives you a MediaStreamObject - LocalMediaStream. HTML5ROCKS has a tutorial in which you can relay the camera. Is it possible to store the LocalMediaStream in localstorage & then pass on the raw bytearray data to the server?

Here is the HTML5ROCKS writeup : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. 
Another problem is that localstorage is usually limited in size (a few megabytes). Yet another problem is that raw bytearray data wastes too much space. It would be an uncompressed video which is quickly a few gigabytes in size.